# Flake8 disable all formatting rules

Tags: python, formatting, flake8, python-black

I use `flake8` for linting and `black` for formatting.

`flake8` produces warnings on **execution rules** and **formatting rules**:

[image]

I only want to see **execution rules**. I don't care about **formatting rules** because they'll automatically get fixed by `black` formatting:

[image]

I can disable these rules one at a time by running `flake8 --ignore=E271,E225,W291,E231`. However, there's no exhaustive list of formatting rules to disable, they have to be discovered one at a time. It would be great to have something similar to JavaScript's eslint, where there's a [plugin](https://prettier.io/docs/en/integrating-with-linters.html#disable-formatting-rules) to disable all formatting rules that are covered by the code formatter.

Is there a similar way to disable all the **formatting rules** in `flake8`?

**Solution:** Based on the below answer, I ended up ignoring all formatting rules with this command:

```
flake8 --ignore=E101,E111,E114,E115,E116,E117,E12,E13,E2,E3,E401,E5,E70,W1,W2,W3,W5 file.py
```

Answer (score 7):

I also wanted to disable aesthetic errors. I came up with a slightly different list of what to ignore; this is what I have in my `setup.cfg`.

```
[flake8]
extend-ignore =
    # Indentation — black handles
    E1
    W1
    # Whitespace — black handles
    E2
    W2
    # Blank lines — black handles
    E3
    W3
    # Imports — isort handles
    E4
    W4
    # Line length — black handles
    E5
    W5
    # No lambdas — too strict
    E731
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you can [ignore by error code pattern](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/3.1.1/user/ignoring-errors.html#changing-the-ignore-list), not just specific error codes, e.g. `--ignore=E1,W` for all error codes beginning with E1 and W. [Here's a list](https://pycodestyle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#error-codes) of current error codes you can use to specify the kind of errors you'd like to ignore.

Comment: Thanks for the list of errors. I went through the list and updated the original question with a list of all the warnings I can safely ignore.